# How to "reset" Lovecombo combobox?

Tags: extjs

I have form with lovocombo of cities on it. 
At start current value of lovecombo is emptyText value = "Select city". 
Then i select any options and submit form, and current values changed to 'London' (for example).
Else there is "reset" button on the form, which have handler:

```
handler: function (){

lovecombo.setValue(false);
lovecombo.clearValue();

}
```

but Lovecombo don`t takes on emptyText value = "Select city", when "reset" button is clicked.

How to reset or set emptyText value to Lovecombo?

PS: sorry for my english.

lovecombo homepage http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Since LovCombo extends Ext.form.ComboBox, it inherits the reset() method. Try:

```
handler: function() {
  lovecombo.reset();
}
```